# Passing my PHP variable value to Js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hiii Everyone,

```
<script src="../../record/recordmp3.js?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>&&test_no=<?php echo $_GET['test_no'];?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" data-my_var_1="some_val_1" data-my_var_2="some_val_2" src="/js/somefile.js"></script>
```

And I tried to get that passing value in recordmp3.js is

```
var student_id = this_js_script.attr('data-my_var_1');
var test_no = this_js_script.attr('data-my_var_2');
```

And also by

```
var student_id = "<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>";
var test_no = "<?php echo $_GET['test_no'];?>";
```

And my value is not passing correctly.Instead only '0' is passing In my index page I have some PHP variable value I need to pass that value to recordmp3.js file.Please help me to solve this issue.Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: make sure your `$_GET['id']` is not empty

Comment: Sure @sahil its having value with $id='1' and test_no='2'

Comment: so you mean you are unable to get `<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>` in your js code of first line ?

Comment: Also, are you using any php framework ? how about url rewriting u have into it ?

Comment: I did this and it seems like its working for me https://eval.in/758721

Comment: No.Im not working in framework

Comment: No inside page.I need to retrieve this value in some other file which means(recordmp3.js) .Inisde ths file I need access tht values in Index.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138699/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-mittul-at-technobrave).

Comment: @KavyaShree if you have index.php file .. you can use above code which i mentioned in link and in .js file you can get value by passing thay query string's key.

Answer (score 1):

I tried like below its working fine

```
<script src="../../record/recordmp3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
MYLIBRARY.init(["<?php echo $id; ?>", "<?php echo $test_no; ?>"]); 
MYLIBRARY.helloWorld(); 
</script>

var MYLIBRARY = MYLIBRARY || (function(){ 
var _args = {}; // private 

return { 
init : function(Args) { 
_args = Args; 
// some other initialising 
}, 
helloWorld : function() { 
window.id=  _args[0]; 
window.test_no= _args[1];
} 
}; 
}());
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert these values to json array.  You cannot directly assign the php values to JavaScript variables.
Hope this answer is useful.  Please let me know if you find any difficulties on converting to json value.

Comment: The second answer is not a best practice,  have you tried that to converting to json array? Here is the syntax, $val = 'your php values' ;
$json = json_encode($val);

Comment: try this and let me know.                                                                                               <?php
$ar = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'strawberry');
echo json_encode($ar); // ["apple","orange","banana","strawberry"]
?>

Comment: I had uploaded my own try.check it

Comment: This should definitely work. You can pass the JSON string output by json_encode to a JavaScript variable as follows:

<script type="text/javascript">
// pass PHP variable declared above to JavaScript variable
var ar = <?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;
</script>

Answer (score -1):

`.js` files don't execute and compile the php files,so in order to access the php variables in javascript the file should be `.php`.

**script.php**

```
<?php
  $foo = 'Hello cool';
?>
<script>
var foo ='<?php echo $foo ?>';
console.log(foo);
</script>
```

i hope this example will solve your issue